# Concatenate user input in Html form and assigning an ID to it, in order to submit in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, mqtt

everyone I am newbie to JavaScript and Html and i am trying to concatenate the user input in html form and giving an ID and submit, in order to give command to my controller to act accordingly.

This is basically setting up schedule for port 1 and command goes like [NORMAL 122(STARTTIMESTOPTIME DAYSESSION)I haven't included session yet.

```
function Port1_sch_On_off(){
        if(connected_flag==1){
            client.subscribe("lazy/test");
            message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("NORMAL 122 + document.getElementById('port1_timeday'.value)");
            message.destinationName = "lazy/test";
            client.send(message);
            }
            else {
                console.log("not connected")
            }
        return false;   
    }

<tr height=40>
        <td><style="text-align:middle">PORT1_SCH_ON_OFF</td>
        <td width=40></td>
        <td><form id="port1_timeday" oninput="port1_timeday.value = start_time.valueAsNumber start_day.valueAsNumber stop_time.valueAsNumber stop_day ">
            <input name="start_time" id="start_time" type="time" min="00:00" max="24:00" required/> 
            <span class="hours"></span> 
            <label for="start_day">Day:</label> 
            <select name="start_day" id="start_day"> 
                <option value="1">MON</option>
                <option value="2">TUES</option>
                <option value="3">WED</option>
                <option value="4">THRUS</option>
                <option value="5">FRI</option>
                <option value="6">SAT</option>
                <option value="0">SUN</option>
            </select>           
            </label>
            <input name="stop_time" id="stop_time" type="time" min="00:00" max="24:00" required/> 
            <label for="stop_day">Day:</label> 
            <select name="stop_day" id="stop_day"> 
                <option value="1">MON</option>
                <option value="2">TUES</option>
                <option value="3">WED</option>
                <option value="4">THRUS</option>
                <option value="5">FRI</option>
                <option value="6">SAT</option>
                <option value="0">SUN</option>
            </select>
            </label>
            <output name="port1_timeday" for="start_time start_day stop_time stop_day"></output></td>
            <input type="button" onclick="Port1_sch_On_off()" value="Port1_timeday">
            </form>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

And also I have to add eventlistener for the same with which i haven't started yet.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Provide a descripition of what is not working.

Comment: I'm trying to concatenate the user inputs(day and time) into a string and pass it to function in javaScript using a onsubmit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two main ways to concatenate in javascript :

using the + operator :

```
message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("NORMAL 122 " + document.getElementById('port1_timeday'.value));
```

or

using string interpolation :

```
message = new Paho.MQTT.Message(`NORMAL 122 + ${document.getElementById('port1_timeday'.value)}`);
```

I hope this answers your question :D

**edit 1 :**

This function will return your user input cancatenated as such "STARTDAYSTARTTIMESTOPTIMESTOPDAY", you can modify it to return the values in any order :

```
function cancat_day_time() {
    start_time = document.getElementById("start_time").value;
    start_day = document.getElementById("start_day").value;
    stop_time = document.getElementById("stop_time").value;
    stop_day = document.getElementById("stop_day").value;

    return `${start_day}${start_time}${stop_day}${stop_time}`; 
}
```

You can then use it in your function Port1_sch_On_off() like this :

```
function Port1_sch_On_off() {
    if (connected_flag == 1) {
        client.subscribe("lazy/test");
        message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("NORMAL 122 " + cancat_day_time());
        message.destinationName = "lazy/test";
        client.send(message);
    } else {
        console.log("not connected")
    }
    return false;
}
```

**edit 2 :**

This is the HTML code that works for me :

```
<tr height=40>
    <td></td>
    <td width=40></td>
    <td>
        <form id="port1_timeday" oninput="">
            <input name="start_time" id="start_time" type="time" min="00:00" max="24:00" required/>
            <span class="hours"></span>
            <label for="start_day">Day:</label>
            <select name="start_day" id="start_day">
                <option value="1">MON</option>
                <option value="2">TUES</option>
                <option value="3">WED</option>
                <option value="4">THRUS</option>
                <option value="5">FRI</option>
                <option value="6">SAT</option>
                <option value="0">SUN</option>
            </select>
            </label>
            <input name="stop_time" id="stop_time" type="time" min="00:00" max="24:00" required/>
            <label for="stop_day">Day:</label>
            <select name="stop_day" id="stop_day">
                <option value="1">MON</option>
                <option value="2">TUES</option>
                <option value="3">WED</option>
                <option value="4">THRUS</option>
                <option value="5">FRI</option>
                <option value="6">SAT</option>
                <option value="0">SUN</option>
            </select>
            </label>
    </td>
    <input type="button" onclick="Port1_sch_On_off()" value="Port1_timeday">
    </form>
</tr>
```

Comment: Okay,this solution will probably work but I'm trying to concatenate the inputs entered by user (day and time) and then call it in Port1_sch_on_off in the way you have shown above.

Comment: I don't know exactly what are you trying to accomplish, but your html code contains some errors and can be simplified

Comment: hey,thank you,your solution worked for me .Now, i am trying to replicate the similar thing with different names for port2 but html console showsonMessageArrived:NORMAL 122[object HTMLInputElement][object HTMLInputElement] [object HTMLSelectElement][object HTMLSelectElement]